# What could have caused a corrupted partition?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu (Xubuntu to be precise), about a week later Windows 7 had trouble writing to one of my partitions. I ran `chkdsk /f` from Windows and everything worked again. About five days later I try to mount the same partition and Ubuntu says it is corrupted. Windows show only bootsqm.dat.

Everything I lost is backed up, so I don't really care about any recovery and I could reformat the partition and restore easy enough, but then I wouldn't have learned anything:)

If there are logs on Windows/Ubuntu that I could look through to make sure this doesn't happen again that would be awesome.

My System Setup:

- MS-DOS Partition Table with two primary partitions and an extended partition. The one I have been having problems with is "Cloud"
- Windows - Primary
- Xubuntu - Primary
- Storage - Logical on Extended
- Cloud   - NTFS Logical on Extended (Where I keep my Google Drive folder)
- Note: no Swap

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is surely that your hard disk is failing. No other reason can damage both operative systems. Do a back up of your data and buy a new hard drive.